# What happened to BasePagingLoadResult in gxt 3.x?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I'm developing a GXT app and in the examples I have seen so far on the web there is reference to the class `com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.loader.BasePagingLoadResult`. However, this is deprecated in GXT 3.0 jar I am using (3.0.1). What is the correct way to use this now? Do I need to implement the interface myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface is already implemented in [PagingLoadResultBean](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/data/shared/loader/PagingLoadResultBean.html) (A [ListLoadResultBean](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/data/shared/loader/ListLoadResultBean.html) that adds support for paging properties as described by [PagingLoadResult](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/gxt-3.0.0/javadoc/gxt/com/sencha/gxt/data/shared/loader/PagingLoadResult.html).):

For example:

```
@Override public PagingLoadResult<Data> getMyData(PagingLoadConfig loadConfig) {
        ArrayList<Data> dataList;
        dataList = obtainDataMethod(); //Your method to obtain your list of data
        return new PagingLoadResultBean<Data>(dataList, loadConfig.getOffset(), loadConfig.getLimit());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class, is more simple

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
list.add(p1);
list.add(p2);
ListLoadResultBean<Person> result = new ListLoadResultBean<Person>();
result.setData(list);
```